# CSS border-radius without vendor prefixes?

Tags: jquery, mozilla, css

Is there any way to make radius border without `-moz`, cause this only works for on Mozilla browsers?

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft:3%;
-moz-border-radius-topright:3%;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:3%;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3%;
```

Comment: The problem here is that `border-radius-[VH]` is only implemented by Mozilla. The standard is `border-[V]-[H]-radius`.

Comment: @BoltClock, that's right, but if he is using same values on all 4 corners he can use shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the jQuery way and get the excellent round corner plugin at

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (not images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like $('div, p').corner('10px'); and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
    <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

Comment: Uhhmm, this "working" example shows 2 squares with hard corners for me on chrome...

Answer (score 5):

Use a vendor prefix for `-webkit` and the prefixless version, like so...

```
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

I'm pretty sure Firefox 4 is supporting the vendorless property now.

Comment: It sure is. So are Opera 10.50 and IE9.

Comment: All latest builds of popular browsers support `border-radius`, but not everyone is using latest.

Answer (score 1):

```
-moz-border-radius:3%;
-webkit-border-radius:3%;
-o-border-radius:3%;
border-radius:3%;
```

etc, it is not a standard**ized** yet so you <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't use only `border-radius`.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

Comment: It *is* a standard by now. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) which has Candidate Recommendation status by now. But you probably still want the prefixed versions in there to cater for the people who don't update their browsers.

Comment: @Joey, I know, it is a standard, I haven't expressed properly, what I meant is, eg FF4 is pretty much new, imagine how many users are currently on FF3.x and will stay on it for a long period. It is better to include all of them rules, can't hurt.

Comment: -o-border-radius never worked for me. Opera does work with border-radius since 10.5.